# Parsing child element from parent

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following element selected:

```
>>> order
<Element Order at 0x10364b960>
```

To get all of its children elements, I can do:

```
>>> order.getchildren()
[<Element Digital_Order at 0x10364b910>, <Element Identifier at 0x10364b8c0>, 
<Element Sold_To_Party at 0x10364b9b0>, <Element Customer_PO_No at 0x10364ba00>, 
<Element PO_Date at 0x10364ba50>, <Element Customer_Name at 0x10364baa0>, 
<Element Buyer_Name at 0x10364baf0>, <Element Approval_Dt at 0x10364bb40>, 
<Element Approval_By at 0x10364bb90>, <Element Order_Creation_Dt at 0x10364bbe0>, 
<Element Order_Instructions at 0x10364bc30>, <Element Order_Items at 0x10364bc80>]
```

How would I select a specific child, in this case `Identifier`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`order.find('Identifier')`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#find) to retrieve the first `Identifier` child element.

In case you want an array containing all matching elements, use `findall` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 1):

An `Element` in lxml is a full tree, so you can use the [`find`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#find) or [`findall`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#findall) methods at will:

```
order.find('Identifier')
```

In other words, it works just the same as for finding your order element in the first place.